# how to find a picture in linux by color

Tags: images

Is there a code or program that allows a user to search for images with a specific color in the photo

I've recently ran a image recovery tool on my Linux distribution and there's over 40,000 Pictures to go through, I understand that i can narrow these down tremendously by size, but if i had to guess I'd say that the size is all messed up and inaccurate from being accidentally wiped.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [digikam](https://www.digikam.org/).

It is a KDE software for managing photos. It has many features and one of them is creating a fingerprint of every photo and then allowing to search by scribbling a rough sketch.

https://userbase.kde.org/Digikam/Performing_Fuzzy_Searches_In_digiKam

[image: screenshot of fuzzy search]